# redirect to specific route after file creation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, pdfmake

I have a code that I generate a pdf file. But when the user clicks on the generate pdf button, I would like it to be redirected to a specific route. this route would be: services/pdf/:serviceId. I have already declared the path of this route in my router.tsx file and every time the pdf is opened in a new tab but the address that is generated always ends up in my home and not in the route I would like. How can I resolve this?
my router file:

```
<Route exact path="/services/pdf/:serviceId" component={TabPayment} />
```

EDIT:
I created a function using pdfmake. the pdf is generated normally. before, I created the pdf like this:

```
 pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinitions).download();
```

but this caused the pdf to download automatically. now i use

```
 pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinitions).open();
```

this causes it to open in a new tab. to generate the pdf, I created a button and generate the pdf as follows

```
<Button variant="contained" sx={{ marginRight: '5px' }} onClick={generatePDF}>PDF</Button>
```

the generatePDF is the function I used to create the pdf

Comment: Because I was asked to create the route from the service id :(

Comment: You should make clear which exact package you're using/facing problems with. If you're using this package `https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfmake`, then it seems to have a `write` method that takes a custom route as a parameter. Check an example here: https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/examples/tables.js